# Как сделать отсчет счетчика слайдера с 1, а не 0 в owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Слайдер owl carousel. 
Как сделать отсчитывание счетчика от 1, а не нуля как сейчас?

**[Песочница CodePen](https://codepen.io/Alexandr59/pen/BPJZBL)**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=121" alt="img1" /></div>
<div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=232" alt="img1" /></div>
<div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=343" alt="img1" /></div>
<div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=454" alt="img1" /></div>
  <div class="slides"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=454" alt="img1" /></div>
</div>
<div id="counter"></div> 
</div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  autoplay: 2000,
  items:1,
  onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
  onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
});

function counter(event) {
   var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
    var items     = event.item.count;     // Номер слайда
    var item      = event.page.index + 1;     // Позиция
  $('#counter').html(""+item+" of "+items)
}
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Параметр `startPosition` пробовали задавать?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `owl.owlCarousel({})` параметр `startPosition: 1` и все получится.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  autoplay: 2000,
  items:1,
  startPosition: 1,
  onInitialized  : counter, //When the plugin has initialized.
  onTranslated : counter //When the translation of the stage has finished.
});
```

[Ссылка на песочницу](https://codepen.io/straven/pen/GByOBW)

Comment: startPosition: 1, ставит второй слайдер первым.  К сожалению, никак не влияет на счетчик. Проверял в песочнице

Comment: Тогда нужно переписывать код библиотеки. Циклы по умолчанию стартуют с 0. Придется менять строку которая выводит информацию о слайдах.